# How to get event in onChange of Editor in Draft.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I want to use `event.stopPropagation()` in onChange of Editor.

```
class MyEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = (editorState) => {
      // Is there a way to get event here?
    };
  }

  render() {
    // ...
    return (
      <Editor editorState={editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the event? Thanks

**UPDATE**: add my case. I have an editor, it loads data from Redux saved in IndexedDB. Since the selection (cursor) will lose after `convertToRaw` and `convertFromRaw`, so I use a localEditorState to maintain the cursor.

The editor has a wrapper. If user click the editor wrapper, I want to move the cursor to end. If user click the editor inside, I want the cursor use the selection info from localEditorState.

```
class Send extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      localEditorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
      shouldMoveCursorToEnd: false
    };

    // ...
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { loadEditor } = this.props;
    loadEditorFromIndexedDB();
  }

  onEditorWrapperClick() {
    const { editorState } = this.props;

    this.domEditor.focus();
    this.setState({ shouldMoveCursorToEnd: true });
  }

  onEditorChange(newEditorState) {
    // Without event.stopPropagation(), onEditorWrapperClick will also run, which is not what I want

    this.setState({ shouldMoveCursorToEnd: false });
    this.updateEditorText(newEditorState);
  }

  updateEditorText(newEditorState) {
    const { updateEditor } = this.props;

    this.setState({ localEditorState: newEditorState });

    updateEditor(newEditorState);
    this.saveToIndexedDB({ newEditorState });
  }

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.props;
    const { localEditorState, shouldMoveCursorToEnd } = this.state;

    const editorStateWithSelection = shouldMoveCursorToEnd
      ? EditorState.moveFocusToEnd(editorState)
      : EditorState.acceptSelection(editorState, localEditorState.getSelection());

    return (
        <form onClick={this.onEditorWrapperClick}>
          <Editor editorState={editorStateWithSelection} onChange={this.onEditorChange} />
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Send;
```

Comment: It looks like Draft.js is not exposing the actual event when the onChange happens. What's your use case?

Comment: @Grandas just added!

Comment: Could you describe the scenario in a bit more detail? That's how I currently understand it:
1. User clicks the editor wrapper
2. Some DOM element gets focused, component rerenders because state changed
3. On the re-render, EditorState changes because of shouldMoveCursorToEnd 
4. The editor state change triggers the `this.onEditorChange` (Which is not the desired behaviour to you?)

Comment: @Grandas right now when user click editor inside, it will trigger both `onEditorChange` and `onEditorWrapperClick`, so `shouldMoveCursorToEnd` will change to `false` first, and then `true` immediately. The cursor will go to correct place first, and then jump to the end immediately. I want it stay at `false` when user click editor inside.

Comment: Have you tried calling `EditorState.moveFocusToEnd(editorState)` in the onEditorWrapperChange and `EditorState.acceptSelection(editorState, localEditorState.getSelection())` in `updateEditorText` while removing it from the render?

I'm thinking the re-renders of updating the state might be causing some weird side effects. 

If that doesn't work, you could do something hacky like setting a local variable like `this.clickedOnWrapper = true` in `onEditorWrapperClick ` and then having something like `if (this.clickedOnWrapper) { this.clickedOnWrapper = false; return;}` in `onEditorChange `

Comment: @Grandas thanks for help! However, moving them to function won't help. Since after updating editorState in those two functions, they still need to though store (convertToRaw), when they back (convertFromRaw) and use `const { editorState } = this.props;` in renders, they lose selection info again. I will see if I can find another solution or change my structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the solution you are looking for will involve manipulating the `onMouseDown()` synthetic event of your `<Editor/>` component to `preventDefault()` / `stopPropagation()` and execute custom logic accordingly.

Clicks anywhere else inside your `<Wrapper/>` component should set editor state to place the caret at the end of your editor.

Your resulting implementation might look similar to the following:

```
// Component.
<form onMouseDown={this.handleWrapperClick}>
  <Editor .. onMouseDown={this.handleEditorClick}/>
</form>


// Logic.
handleWrapperClick = (event) => {

  // Manipulate editorState to focus / place caret at end of <Editor/>.
}
handleEditorClick = (event) => {

  // Intercept / Cancel Click Event.
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()

  // Set editorState to match selection info from localEditorState.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

the default parameter passed to your onChange method is the event object. If I understand your intention correctly, I would modify the code as follows:

```
class MyEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onChange = (event, editorState) => {
    // event passed from Editor component
  };

  render() {
    // ...
    return (
      <Editor editorState={editorState} onChange={event => this.onChange(event, editorState)} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your problem, I would try add an additional parameter to accept the event passed from the Editor component, please see the updated code above